# Edittext in Expandablelistview gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        //expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        //expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                + " -> "
                                + expandableListDetail.get(
                                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
    }
}
}

CustomExpandableListAdapter.java

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> 
expandableListTitle,
HashMap<String, List<String>> 
expandableListDetail) {
try {
this.context = context;
this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
}
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
return 
this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
.get(expandedListPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup 
parent) {
try {
final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, 
expandedListPosition);
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}
EditText expandedListEditText = (EditText) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
expandedListEditText.setText(expandedListText);
return convertView;
}catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
return null;
}
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
return 
this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("/Test","/Excp due to"+e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

I am trying to add EditText to Expandablelistview but not TextViews. when I am adding adapter to Expandablelistview, Its giving null pointer exception beacause extendableListDetail has nothing. How to overcome this. Tell me how to add Edittexts to expandable listviews. please help me.[This is the exception I am getting while debugging code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZK8P.png)

Comment: you have a null pointer exception which can be fixed in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Add the exception message to the question please.

Comment: and your main problem is that expandableListDetail is being null

Comment: I dont know what changes I have to do my code for handle this null pointer exception. Can you please explain me?@YamenNassif

Comment: you didn't define  **expandableListDetail** . So ,It is null that's why you have a crash

Comment: how can I define expandableListDetail? @ImenNmn